Undefined control sequence for the inverse trigonometric functions in an array
If I put for example the \arctan out the table the code works finely.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{.....}

 $\arctan f$

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm}|}
\hline
$y=\arcsin\varphi(x)$ e $y=\arccos\varphi(x)$ & $\{ -1 \leq \varphi(x) \leq 1\}\cap \dom(\varphi(x))$ \\ \hline
%$y=\arctan \phi(x)$ e $y=\arccot(\varphi(x))$ & $\dom \varphi(x)$ \\
%$y=\operatorname{arctg}(\varphi(x))$ e $y=\operatorname{arccotg}( \varphi(x))$& $\dom \varphi(x)$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

I don't understand actually because it gives me this error within a simple table. To delete the error during the compilation I must use \operatorname{}{}.
   ! Undefined control sequence.
l.13     $y=\arctan \phi(x)$ e $y=\arccot
                                         ( \varphi(x))$& $\dom \varphi(x)$ \\
?  


 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools,array}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{.....}
    
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm}|}
    \hline
    $y=\arcsin\varphi(x)$ e $y=\arccos\varphi(x)$ & $\{ -1 \leq \varphi(x) \leq 1\}\cap \dom(\varphi(x))$ \\ \hline
    $y=\arctan \phi(x)$ e $y=\arccot(\varphi(x))$ & $\dom \varphi(x)$ \\
    %$y=\operatorname{arctg}(\varphi(x))$ e $y=\operatorname{arccotg}( \varphi(x))$& $\dom \varphi(x)$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}


Nothing to do with beamer, you'd get the same error with \documentclass{article} \begin{document} $\arccot$ \end{document} 

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you. What is the problem?

You are using undefined macros. Either load the appropriate package or define them yourself.

Your example is so far from minimal. From such an experienced user that's really disappointing.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I wonder why you always put everything into a fight.

I'm not fighting. I'm just disappointed that a long term user doesn't put a bit of effort into their question.

Your new example would a) not reproduce the error message you show and b) now has other errors

the error message that you show is clearly not from the code posted.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you so much.

even now you could/should edit this question to be more reasonable. The first line is false, (\arccot would give an error out of the table)  and the error message and posted code do not match (the posted code gives an undefined command \dom error).

@DavidCarlisle You're right. I have put, now, \DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}. If I do other changes the question is different from the original. The problem is \arccot !!

The error message you show is not produced by the code you show. Also very far from minimal.


To delete the error during the compilation I must use \operatorname{}{}.

You do not have to use \operatorname. You could also run
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}

where \DeclareMathOperator is an amsmath-package macro that you're already using -- to define \dom.

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Domini delle funzioni principali, seconda parte}

\begin{table}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}p{4.7cm}<{$}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}p{6.1cm}<{$} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Funzione} & \textbf{Dominio} \\ 
\midrule
y=\sin \varphi(x),\, \cos \varphi(x) 
   & \dom(\varphi(x)) \\ 
\addlinespace
y=\tan \varphi(x) 
   & \{ \varphi(x) \neq \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, 
     \, k\in\mathbb{Z} \}\cap \dom(\varphi(x)) \\ 
\addlinespace
y=\cot \varphi(x) 
   & \{ \varphi(x) \neq k\pi, 
     \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}\cap \dom(\varphi(x)) \\ 
\addlinespace
y=\arcsin\varphi(x),\, \arccos\varphi(x) 
   & \{ -1\leq\varphi(x)\leq 1\}\cap\dom(\varphi(x)) \\ 
\addlinespace
y=\arctan\varphi(x),\, \arccot\varphi(x) 
   & \dom(\varphi(x)) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\caption{\dots}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Great Mico. Thank you infinitely ALWAYS.

For sansmathfonts MikTeX has asked me to install an add-on during compilation: MikTeX didn't have the fonts.

@Sebastiano - I double-checked and realized that MacTeX2024 does feature the sansmathfonts package. (I think I was thrown off earlier by Metafont getting involved to create a raster font image.) I'll update my answer to allow for this package. I think the main difference will be a "thicker" \varphi symbol.

Either use a package which defines the undefined macros or define them yourself.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mismath}
\begin{document}
$\arccot$
\end{document}


One might argue that \arccot should be defined, for the standard operator “arccotangent”.
It isn't, for the simple reason that Knuth didn't think to it. Plain TeX defines
\log \lg \ln
\lim \limsup \liminf
\sin \arcsin \sinh
\cos \arccos \cosh
\tan \arctan \tanh
\cot \coth
\sec \csc
\max \min \sup \inf
\arg \ker \dim \hom \det
\exp \Pr \gcd \deg
I used the same order as in plain.tex (which is quite peculiar, to be honest). Notable absences are those of \arccot and \lcm.
Lamport simply took the same list; amsmath added two operators, namely
\injlim \projlim
with their variants \varinjlim and \varprojlim.
However amsmath provides a way to define operators at will with
\DeclareMathOperator
\DeclareMathOperator*

the latter defining an operator that takes limits. So, for instance, you can do in the preamble
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}    % arccotangent
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}      % cokernel
\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup} % essential supremum (measure theory)
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min} % minimum argument
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max} % minimum argument

For a “one-shot” operator, you can use, in the document body,
\operatorname{Var}

if variance is used just one or two times.
Many Italian books (unfortunately) use “sen” for the sine, “tg” for the tangent and “cotg” for the cotangent. Define them accordingly; a possible strategy could be
\let\sin\relax \DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{sen}
\let\tan\relax \DeclareMathOperator{\tan}{tg}
\let\cot\relax \DeclareMathOperator{\cot}{cotg}

so commenting out these redefinitions would turn all operators into the international form, because the input would still be with \sin and so on.

+1. In fact, the arccot operator is absent in scientific calculators.
